# Как сделать программу для коррекции цвета монитора на python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно написать программу для коррекции цвета.
Пример: Исправить аппаратную проблему - экран потемнел в одном углу.
Принцип работы: Есть графический файл, прозрачный, но в одном углу немного белое пятно. Нужно программой наложить этот рисунок на экран, поверх всех приложений.
Вопрос: Возможно ли это сделать на python? Если нет, то на чем возможно? И как?